# jsPDF: Is there a way to use shading partterns to fill a rect wiht a color gradient?

Tags: jspdf

I have a rather complex document that is drawn from scratch using jsPDF.

I want to clarify that this is not a website. This is run as as script using node and the output is the final PDF file. The input is another file that configures the content for the PDF.

Now I have new specs on what the PDF needs to look like and this includes a gradient on the  background of the entire page.

I've been reading at it seems pretty clear that jsPDF does not support gradients. However, it has been suggested here:

https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/2289

That it would be possible to add gradients by using Shading Patterns, but I can't find a single example on how this would work.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to add gradients or point me to an example of Shading Parterns begin use with jsPDF to generate a file that has a gradient?.

PS: The link in the website I mentioned above does not work for me (I get 429 Too many requests when I try to go there), In case it works for someone else.

Comment: Ok, and would you have any Idea how I would go about using the advanced api amode?

Comment: I know you are trying to help. But I'm really at a complete loss with your suggestion or instruction. The only thing I found is this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-yworks/v/2.1.0 that seesm to be an entirely different package. I still see no example on how to use a ShadingPattern and the 1 line code of how to use the advanceAPI, frankly tells me nothing. I'm, not that well versed in JS, apparently. Thank you anyways

Comment: I've never really thought of setting the image as a backdrop. I could try to ask our graphical designer for one

Comment: Got any update?

Comment: @LeonardoViada. No, not really. The graphical designer simply updated the design so the gradient was no necessary

Answer (score 1):

It appears the functionality from jspdf-yworks has been merged into the main jsPDF codebase, and the jspdf-yworks repo says you can use the advanced API like this:

```
const pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.advancedAPI(pdf => {
// Able to invoke advanced API methods inside this callback
});
```

Inside that callback, you need to add the [Shading Pattern](https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF-API.ShadingPattern.html). But note that the jsPDF code says that the addShadingPattern function (found that mentioned in [this isssue](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/2289#issuecomment-1308630398)) is only to register a pattern **for later use**. So the first step is to register it, with a unique user-provided key and a ShadingPattern instance. ShadingPattern at minimum takes a type (either 'axial' or 'radial', an array of coordinates, and an array of colors.

```
pdf.addShadingPattern('unique-pattern-key', new ShadingPattern('axial', 
[0, 0, 500, 30],
[{
    offset: 0,
    color: [0, 0, 0] //RGB as an array
  },
  {
    offset: 0.15,
    color: [255, 255, 255]
  }
]));
```

Like I said before, all this does is **register** the pattern at that key, so you then need to create an object and fill it with the pattern. You do that by providing the fill method with a [PatternData](https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#PatternData) object. This worked for me for a rectangle (it threw an error for me without a value for matrix):

```
pdf.rect(0, 0, 500, 30).fill({
       key: 'unique-pattern-key',
       matrix: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
});
```

So, altogether, your creation of a gradient rectangle should look like this:

```
const pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.advancedAPI(pdf => {
    pdf.addShadingPattern('unique-pattern-key', new ShadingPattern('axial', 
        [0, 0, 500, 30],
        [{
            offset: 0,
            color: [0, 0, 0] //RGB as an array
          },
          {
            offset: 0.15,
            color: [255, 255, 255]
          }
        ]));
        pdf.rect(0, 0, 500, 30).fill({
           key: 'unique-pattern-key',
           matrix: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        });
});
```

Comment: Will try this if I ever get the chance. What are the values in the matrix supposed to represent. Why are they all zeros in yours? (I did read that you required it and it threw an error if you didn't use it, but I wanted to know what it's supposed to represent)

Comment: Best I could find was they provide a way to make some sort of transformation on the pattern: https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/Matrix.html Leaving them all zero didn't seem to have an effect on my gradient, which was just a simple left to right between two colors.

Answer (score 0):

@badabingboddaroe answer needs an update

You should use following code

```js
const doc = new jsPDF();
doc.advancedAPI((doc) => {
  const gradientKey = "line-gradient";
  doc.addShadingPattern(
    gradientKey,
    new ShadingPattern(
      "axial",
      [0, 0, pdfWidth, 2],
      [
        {
           offset: 0,
           color: [0, 93, 255], //RGB as an array
        },
        {
           offset: 1,
           color: [33, 221, 255],
         },
      ]
    )
  );
  doc.rect(x, y, width, height).fill({ key: gradientKey, matrix: doc.Matrix(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) });
}
```

Note that you need to set `matrix = doc.Matrix(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`